# Unable to obtain Android SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, dictionary

I have looked at several posted solutions to similar questions, but none of them have worked. In the code below findFragmentById always returns null. I'm invoking MapLocationFragment from another fragment.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapLocationFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private String tag;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MapLocationFragment() {}   // Required

    private FragmentActivity context;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Log.d(tag, "onAttach");
        this.context = (FragmentActivity)context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tag = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        Log.d(tag, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(tag, "onCreateView");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        SupportMapFragment frag1 = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
              .findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And the fragment layout (tried both fragment and FrameLayout)

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.spireon.fai.fleetlocate.MapLocationFragment">
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no `android:name` attribute for a `FrameLayout`. That is an attribute for `<fragment>`.

So, let's pretend that instead of `<FrameLayout>`, you have `<fragment>` instead, as you hint in your question.

In that case, your problem is that you are trying to find `R.id.mapFragment` before you inflate the layout that contains `R.id.mapFragment`. You need to inflate the layout before you can use `findViewById()` or `findFragmentById()` to access the contents of that layout.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake of not inflating the view prior to looking for the fragment reference (I modified the code in the post accordingly). However, findFragmentById() still returns null.

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

inside your xml File use:

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="dz.android.grcm.WorkaroundMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:fragmentExitTransition="@layout/yourXmlFile" />
```

inside your manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="packageName"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

     <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <permission
      android:name="packageName.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="packageName.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your_APIKEY_"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name="packageName.Time_Picker"
             android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

for me it works with google_play_services_version : 7095000 and Android API 23
don't forget API_KEY, you have to générate it, refer to this link : [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com)

try it i hope it helps you .

Comment: Amir Thanks, I have the application working using layouts but want to change it to a single layout and the rest being fragments. The map is the only fragment giving me difficulty..

Answer (score 0):

After creating a new emulator, it started to work using the getChildFragmentManager() call. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem with **SupportMapFragment** i don't find it inside gms library the solution is to add this class **WorkaroundMapFragment** to your package:

```
package dz.android.grcm;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;;

public class WorkaroundMapFragment extends MapFragment {
    private OnTouchListener mListener;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstance) {
        View layout = super.onCreateView(layoutInflater, viewGroup, savedInstance);

        TouchableWrapper frameLayout = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());

        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

        ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(frameLayout,
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        return layout;
    }

    public void setListener(OnTouchListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnTouchListener {
        public abstract void onTouch();
    }

    public class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {

        public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mListener.onTouch();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mListener.onTouch();
                    break;
            }
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

then you call this class like this :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inscriptionmed);
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        // *************Fix Scroll Map*******************************
        if (map == null) {
            map = ((WorkaroundMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.partentScroll); 

            ((WorkaroundMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map))
                    .setListener(new WorkaroundMapFragment.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTouch() {
                            mScrollView
                                    .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        }
                    });

        }
```